# Can't install AMD graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

I just switched from my old BackTrack 5 installation to a Kubuntu installation. Sadly, I can't install the AMD graphic drivers. On my BT5 installation everything went fine, but my Kubuntu installation is missing something to install them. Here is my log:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
fglrx installation requires that the system has gcc tool. 
gcc cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. 
Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

I installed the gcc thing via `sudo apt-get install gcc`. This went fine, but I don't know where to obtain the other stuff. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Also, I've downloaded these drivers from the AMD homepage for my 4xxx graphic card. Then I've extracted it to receive the *.run file and opened this one by typing `sudo ./ati-xxx.run`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also install the kernel header files. For that, just open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If you do not have any make-tools or autoconf/autotools installed, you must also type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks, I did so and also performed a reboot after this. I already had build-essential installed. Unfortunately, the error log stays the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the commands you are typing?

Comment: I've edited my question.