# How to enable second monitor using AMD A10-7870K with Radeon R7 graphics

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

My second monitor is not detected. "Displays" shows only one monitor. Both monitors work separately, just not in dual-monitor mode. With both cables plugged in, only the monitor connected to HDMI is detected. If I unplug the HDMI cable, the monitor on the DVI-D cable is detected. Both monitors are Dell 23".

Ubuntu 14.04.5, fresh install with all updates.

AMD A10-7870K APU with Radeon R7 graphics. I do not have a separate GPU card.

Using X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)

Comment: What's your computer make and model?

Comment: Asus A88X-Pro mobo

Comment: You may want to read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics/

Comment: I can get the second monitor working with a DisplayPort cable, so it appears that using the DVI and HDMI outputs at the same time is not possible.