# 14.04: Can't install fglrx on Dell with AMD graphic card

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

after that I upgrade my kernel to 4.4 version, my AMD driver cannot install since. See the bug:

```
  vitor@vitor-PC:~$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install fglrx
  package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not     going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to     be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I haven't solved it yet. But I found out what's wrong.

I'd like some expert advice to, but it looks like FGLRX does NOT work on Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest 14.04 (5) because it is not compatible with a recent version of XORG.

Here's an explanation:

[Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics)

```
Please Note: 14.04.5 brought with it Xorg 1.18, which is what causes the problem in 16.04 to begin with. Luckily, it is completely possible to downgrade Xorg to 1.16 (on 14.04), so you can still use fglrx. Read here.
```

I actually needed the AMD APK to code in OpenCL 2.0, so I guess I just have to avoid AMD drivers and find another way to install OpenCL.

One suggested solution in the linked page is:

```
Try out Oibaf's drivers.

They work for AMD, NVIDIA and Intel, so you can even try them out if you dislike NVIDIA's proprietary drivers or are hoping for more performance from your Intel card.
They support newer OpenGL and OpenCL versions, so stuff that depends on those will work.
They claim to be optimized, so you could see an real boost in performance.
```

Oibaf's driver seems like a great replacement to fglrx, and it probably is. However, if you have a really recent AMD card, you may want to try out AMD's own offering.

Comment: you should add a link to Oibaf's drivers