# Ubuntu fglrx driver is not working

Tags: fglrx, gpu, gpu-driver

I have just installed fglrx driver from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064 and xserver didn't start after reboot.
GPU : Radeon r7 m200
System : Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: 15.04? You need to upgrade or downgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have already tried with 14.04 and 16.10

Comment: 14.04.5, 16.04 and 16.10 all have problems with AMD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics/815592#815592. I don't know why 15.04 isn't working, but we can't help you here. You'll have to delete this and ask on [unix.se], since we don't support end-of-life releases.

Comment: Thanks,  but, which version should I install to avoid that problems?

Comment: Install 14.04 and read the answer I linked, which will tell you how to fix it. You need to downgrade Xorg.

Comment: I have downgraded Xorg, but there was a error while installation process: `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-36-generic (x86_64)`.