# What is the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04 on which fglrx for AMD can be installed?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have an AMD Radeon HD 8730M graphics card. After some online research, I found out that fglrx(proprietary driver from AMD) is not supported on Ubuntu 14.04.5 and Ubuntu 16.04. I have also come to know that Xorg server does not support fglrx from version 1.18 onwards.
I would like to know the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04 (and also the latest kernel version) which I can install and be able to use fglrx driver.
Will fglrx work if I just install Ubuntu 14.04.5 and downgrade Xorg to version 1.16?

Comment: *I think* as long as you don't install the 16.04 HWE stack, you'll be fine... but I'm not positive. Don't quote me on that.

Comment: You can use Ubuntu 14.04.5, just not the 14.04.5 HWE stack. If you have 14.04.5 and need to remove the HWE, see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/827063

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A guaranteed way is to install 14.04, or 14.04.1.

Other HWE stacks for 14.04 will not get updates, except the `xenial` one, that is no good for `fglrx`.

The original 14.04 will be supported till April 2019.

Answer (score 5):

When installing from an ISO the latest ISO you can install from and retain fglrx support, is 14.04.4. The 14.04.5 ISO installs with the kernel and Xorg packages from 16.04 that have been backported for hardware enablement.

If you are running a 14.04 installed prior to 14.04.5, and continue installing standard updates, but DO NOT install the lts-xenial HWE stack by hand, then fglrx should continue to work, even though the *About* information in *System Settings* and elsewhere, will say that you have 14.04.5.

The important part is to NOT be running the lts-xenial kernel and xorg packages, to get fglrx to work.

Comment: It is possible to downgrade Xorg on 14.04.5 (option 5): http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics/815592#815592

Comment: The only problem is that 14.04.4 HWE stack is not supported. I suggest the original 14.04, or 14.04.1.

Answer (score -1):

debian jessie its the best alternative downlad full cd sets and aditionaly find the live cd to start with it the instaler its more like the one of ubuntu
the normal cd set forces u to use the network connection if you are debian newbie dont expect to find the easy menus or aditonal ubuntu software like menu bars. preferable instal live cd then add local cds and use the cd sets
install xfce or kde and then install fglrx dont use gnomeshell unless you know how to enable it for fglrx.

Otherwise find repositories for 14.04.4  and download the full stack and set them as a local repositories meanwhile try change the distro name to something like fglrxUbuntu or something and upload the full repositorie to your server and share it with a webpage to find it online call for help for the name and visuals and the people will came any problems check the forums its more easy than creating linux mint or cinamon
cause everiting was already done it only needs its own name and space

I am also in the same boat as all of you. I was happy with a a full working setup until i lost my drive and now Im strugling with getting everithing to work back again. Also dont fall for 16.04 or highers versions I already tried them and there are only fake hopes. They dont met (feet to) our hardware, we are stuck so hope up its more ease to have a personal repository for backup the drivers published in amd web page are good i tried them in my system and work great with amd radeon hd6250