# What AMD GPU-PRO Driver version should I install if I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I'm about to install the new AMD Driver, although my card isn't "supported" yet, i will give it a try since it is focused on GCN 1.2 and my APU is a Carrizo (which contains that architecture according to [Notebookcheck on Carrizo APUs](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-R6-Carrizo-Benchmarks.144290.0.html). But there are two options to download, one for Ubuntu 14.04.4 and Ubuntu 16.04, but since 14.04.5 bring us the kernel and the graphic stack that 16.04 uses I don't know which one install.

Should i install the 14.04.4 version or 16.04 version?

Thanks!

Comment: My vote is for 16.04 considering 14.04.5 shares the same kernel and HWE.

Comment: If your card isn't supported, I really recommend against trying the driver. On 14.04.5 you can just downgrade Xorg and use `fglrx`. Read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics

Comment: thanks for both of you, i tried installing the driver but it didn't work because of secure boot, and i will check that link Zacharee

Comment: Thanks for the help but it seems that i cant install the old AMD drivers neither because of secure boot, seems i have to wait until i finish my semester to do risky things