# Games not running properly

Tags: drivers, wine, games, amd-graphics

So I installed wine on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to run World of Warcraft 3.3.5a and this is also I see: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrtns.jpg) as you can see it is miss certain textures. I also get a spam of errors in my terminal saying: `err:d3d:resource_init Out of adapter memory
fixme:d3d_texture:texture_init Failed to create surface 0x100ac198, hr 0x8876017c
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
err:d3d:resource_init Out of adapter memory`

I'm very new to Linux ubuntu but I'm guessing it's an driver-related issue. My computer specs: 
Intel i5 6600k CPU
AMD Radeon R9 380 4GB

If I could have any help, It would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could always try reading http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics, but you should never expect games to run well under WINE.

Comment: The Wine AppDB can sometimes help. Pay attention to the wine version(s) and app version(s) in use. AppDB can sometimes provide useful tips/tricks to get a particular game running or improve performance (as in correctly rendering things) ... [WineHQ - World of Warcraft - 3.3.5a](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33768)

Comment: Thanks Zacharee, installing the AMD Pro GPU drivers seemed to fixed it (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Wine's registry editor.

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Wine/Direct3D`

If that doesn't exist create it (right-click, new key).

Add a new string called `VideoMemorySize`, and set it to a preferred amount (>=512) based on your graphics card.

**This manually allocates more Video RAM in Wine, which WoW is eating up.**

Comment: I don't see "Direct3D". Here's an image of my display http://imgur.com/4tQiZJ9 However, installing the AMD PRO GPU drivers seemed to fix the issue (I think)

Comment: If it doesn't exist, create a new key named Direct3D

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Do you know what the optminal value is for me to set with 8gb ram and 4gb video ram?

Comment: @TomKing If you're running on high/max in WoW allocate at least >2GB. If You play other AAA games under Wine I would allocate 3-3.5GB. Leave some for Ubuntu. If this helped please upvote!

Comment: Hate to necroboost but this worked for me with Bridge Commander with the remaster mod here in 2024 on PopOS.