# AMD Driver Query - For Noobs!

Tags: 16.04, games, amd-graphics

I have gotten a new DOS laptop with i7 6th Gen and Radeon R7 M440. Are there drivers available for the R7 M440 card on 16.04? If yes, please direct me to the link. If No, what alternatives do you suggest (apart from windows 10)?

Comment: Found using Google: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04 Is an older release (14.04) an option for you?

Comment: Would the open source drivers be of any use? I do want to have the latest version of Ubuntu (not that i know of the specific advantages).

Comment: Have you tried using the Additional Drivers tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04/14.04.5 and AMD graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics)

Comment: @PauloBotelho No Sir, haven't installed Ubuntu yet.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - I had read this earlier. I'll give it a try nonetheless. Nothing to lose, except for some time and effort. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

A new release just came out recently! http://news.softpedia.com/news/amd-rolls-out-amdgpu-pro-16-40-driver-for-ubuntu-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-509737.shtml

I haven't tried yet but I am on it now. 
Here's the link to AMD: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx