# Radeon r9 390 - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

*Issue*: I'm currently dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04. But, when I boot into Ubuntu after a few minutes, my screen switches to black, my rig continues to run, and I can't access or see anything.

- When I remove my PowerColor PCS+ Radeon R9 390 DirectX GPU and hook up directly to my ASROCK Z97 Extreme6 Mobo, everything works perfectly, sans decent graphics. Albeit it works.
- If I'm hooked up to the 390(via HDMI or DisplayPort), I'll still get the black screen. When I try to reboot for the first time, the GPU fans spin at max speed & I can't get anything to boot. Which, I'll 'reboot' again and everything will work okay.
- I've tried installing the AMDPRO-GPU-Drivers for Linux. I've also disabled Secure Boot & Fast Boot.
- When I try to access the 'Additional Drivers' tab in Updates & Software, the GPU isn't displayed, rather it Ubuntu just says that it has detected some drivers, but won't list the proprietary drivers(i.e., the 390).

I'd appreciate any help at all! It'd be great to be able to use my 390, otherwise, considering just selling & snagging a Nvida GeForce GTX 1070 8GB Video Card(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ)

Comment: *"but won't list the proprietary drivers"* - That's because `fglrx` was removed in 16.04

Comment: @AndroidDev Is there another work around?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics

Comment: Your r9 390 should work fine on the open source amdgpu driver (with decent performance too!). What's the output of `lspci -v | grep -A10 AMD` when the card is plugged in?

Comment: @小太郎 I can't execute the above command, as I get a black screen as soon as I boot into Ubuntu. When I use my motherboard( and unplug the r9 from the motherboard) display port & HDMI port Ubuntu works perfectly.

Comment: Is there any way to set the BIOS to use the iGPU despite having a dGPU plugged in? The name varies across different motherboard manufacturers though... Alternatively, you can hot plug the GPU (plug it in after the system has booted - yes, hotplugging is part of the PCIe standard), though I'm not sure how well consumer boards will react to that

Comment: Actually, before you try any of that, are you able to switch to a TTY? That is, can you `ctrl+alt+F1` to get a console? Are you able to boot into single user mode ("recovery mode" under "Advanced options" in GRUB)?