# Can't watch video without fglrx drivers

Tags: drivers, video, fglrx

I use my PC as a HTPC, it has an APU AMD A6 with an integrated Radeon graphics and currently use Ubuntu 15.10 .
If I don´t use the proprietary drivers (fglrx) the video gets chopy, I really want to update to 16 but it´s useless with the open drivers, is there any solution to this or should I change the distro?

Comment: I installed the Oibaf's drivers from this answer here in my 16.04 with AMD and it plays movies / video files great!  http://askubuntu.com/a/815592/231142

Comment: You can still install fglrx in Ubuntu 14.04.1 (kernel Linux 3.13.0), which is supported until 2019. This is not the best solution I think, but at least you can try if doing so the video playback is fixed.