# Is there a way to use my Dedicated AMD GPU instad of my Integrated Intel GPU in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS yesterday, and I loved it, but the only problem I had is getting a driver to work for my AMD Radeon R5 M330, and switch to it in order to increase performance.

PC Specs:

HP Notebook 15-ac141ne

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @2.30GHz
- GPU1 (Integrated): Intel® HD Graphics 520
- GPU2 (Dedicated): AMD Radeon™ R5 M330
- RAM (IDK if this will have any effect): 4GB DDR3
- HDD: 500GB (260MB Stock Bootloader for Windows, 345.66GB For Windows,
  104.86GB For Ubuntu, 853MB + 14.04GB Stock Recovery data)

I tried AMDGPU-PRO, but after I rebooted my PC it gave me a "Low Graphics" error, then it entered into a login loop. I had to uninstall it from the terminal in order to get to the Unity launcher again.

I know that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has almost no support for AMD GPUs, but maybe there is something I can do in order to make AMDGPU-PRO work properly, or maybe there is another driver that I can use...

Also does 16.10 support AMD GPUs? If it does then that is the solution for my problem.

Comment: I downgraded to 14.04.5, installed fglrx and it made my system unbootable. I was not able to fix it so I had to reinstall 16.04

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)

Comment: Hello there, your GPU is fully supported by the AMDGPU-pro driver package. What you have is a GCN 2.0-based SKU, code-named "Exo Pro DDR3", based on the Tonga line of AMD GPUs. Follow the rest of this answer to solve your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928850/how-can-i-install-amd-gpu-pro-drivers-for-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-or-17-04-deskto/928889#928889