# How to blacklist radeon module?

Tags: kernel, radeon, blacklist

In this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/928889/632192 , step 3:

> Ensure that the radeon module is blacklisted prior to installing the package from AMD.

How can I do that?

Kernel version (output of `uname -r` to be exact):
`4.10.0-26-generic`

Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-blacklist-a-module-on-ubuntu-debian-linux

Comment: Please take a look at these articles: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117135/blacklisting-wont-work-for-kernel-module-radeon) and [2](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/28983/blacklist-disable-uninstall-or-destroy-radeon-module/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an easy way:

1. Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as super user, or create it if it is not there.
2. Add the following line:
   `blacklist radeon`.
3. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` then reboot.

To confirm that the module has been disabled, after rebooting run `lsmod`, and if `radeon` is not listed in the output then it has been blacklisted.