# Mesa Vulkan drivers GPU question

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, vulkan

I am running ubuntu 16.04.4 with budgie desktop - I just installed mesa's vulkan drivers, and when I run vulkaninfo, I can see the gpu it uses is my intel ivy bridge igpu instead of my radeon hd 7870. is there a way i can get it to use the proper gpu?

thanks!

Editing to show the output of `lshw -c video` like dobey wanted

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
      *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7b00000-f7b3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: What driver is being used for the radeon card right now? (`sudo lshw -c video` should show details, if you can [edit] your question to include that info please)

Comment: hi dobey - added the output you wanted.

Comment: It looks like the _radeon_ driver is being used. I'm not sure if Vulkan is supported on that driver, or on your card. I'm also not sure if that card is supported by _amdgpu_ driver either.

Comment: hmm ok - i have tried to install the amdgpu pro drivers with little success - i couldnt log in the last time i tried :(

Comment: hi dobey - this page seems to suggest the HD 7800 series cards are supported by the amdgpu pro driver? https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: It suggests it is supported by the _pro_ driver, yes. You may be able to [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938658/how-to-blacklist-radeon-module) the _radeon_ driver, to see if _amdgpu_ gets picked up. You may not need to install the pro driver, though I suppose if you want Vulkan, you may need the pro drivers.