# How to get OpenCL to work on an AMD GPU with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opencl

I have a PC with a:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] [1002:6821] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

How can I get OpenCL to work on it? I'm not offered a proprietary driver in the Software sources tool, and AFAIK it isn't supported on 16.04 anymore.

clinfo currently lists zero devices.

Comment: Look here http://askubuntu.com/a/815592/231142.  I have tried the oibaf's PPA solution and it worked for me for getting AMD support working on my laptop.

Comment: [This Blog](https://laanwj.github.io/2016/05/06/opencl-ubuntu1604.html) provides a solution that worked on my PC (AMD FirePro M4000 + Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When clinfo shows "Number of platforms                               0",
you probably did not installed an ICD which is needed to use OpenCL-Products (like an Graphics card from AMD).

Use "sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd" for a possible solution.

Comment: I had solved it in the meantime, but that was indeed the solution.

Comment: It is easier to run AMD GPU on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This solved an issue I had as I could not make [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/br/products/davinciresolve/) to work ([RX 580](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580) with AMDGPU-PRO 20.10). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!!! Just spent more than half a day trying to fix `Number of platforms 0` and it solved it.