# Cannot get OpenCL to work with Radeon 5700XT

Tags: radeon, blender, opencl

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with an AMD Radeon 5700XT graphics card. I cannot get OpenCL to work with it. 
I'm using the AMDGPU driver installed with the parameters
--opencl=legacy,rocm
and I installed libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dev and executed ldconfig as suggested here for prorender
https://radeon-pro.github.io/RadeonProRenderDocs/plugins/blender/installation.html#ubuntu
I also installed 
mesa-opencl-icd
as suggested here:
[How to get OpenCL to work on an AMD GPU with Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884483/how-to-get-opencl-to-work-on-an-amd-gpu-with-ubuntu-16-04)

but still nothing.

the output of clinfo is:

> pci id for fd 5: 1002:731f, driver (null) pci id for fd 5: 1002:731f,
>   driver (null) Number of platforms                               2
>   Platform Name                                   Clover   Platform
>   Vendor                                 Mesa   Platform Version
>   OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 19.0.8   Platform Profile
>   FULL_PROFILE   Platform Extensions
>   cl_khr_icd   Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA
>
> Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated
>   Parallel Processing   Platform Vendor
>   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.   Platform Version
>   OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (2906.7)   Platform Profile
>   FULL_PROFILE   Platform Extensions
>   cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices    Platform
>   Host timer resolution                  1ns   Platform Extensions
>   function suffix             AMD
>
> Platform Name                                   Clover Number of
>   devices                                 0
>
> Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated
>   Parallel Processing Number of devices
>   0
>
> NULL platform behavior   clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
>   ...)  No platform   clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No
>   platform   clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
>   clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]                 clCreateContextFromType(NULL,
>   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
>   clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in
>   platform   clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No
>   devices found in platform   clCreateContextFromType(NULL,
>   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
>   clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found
>   in platform   clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No
>   devices found in platform

Which does seem to suggest its finding something, but what I'm actually trying to do is not working, this is for Blender (version 2.80)
in preferences -> system I selected Open CL to enable GPU render, but it says no compatible GPUs found for path tracing.
I also was trying to install AMD prorender as the goal is just to use this GPU to render, whether I can get it working on cycles or prorender...whatever, I juts want to get the GPU rendering.
I get the typical warning about the prorender installer being designed for 16.04 that many report, but the installer itself also warns that it doesn't think my system is capable of Open CL. the installer finishes and I see the prorender addon in blender, but it will not enable and gives an error instead.

Can anyone help get this working? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the solution to my problem in case anyone else is facing it.

When installing the amdgpu driver use these switches:
--opencl=pal,legacy,rocm

after this both my 5700XT and the CPU itself are available under the openCL section.

now I have to figure out why my GPU is taking many many times longer to render a frame than the CPU was, that should not be the case.

Comment: The full command to install the AMD GPU graphics is  ********  ./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy,rocm  ********  I was having issues getting a Blender add-on called radeonprorender to work on my fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I had to unistall the graphics with the command  ********  amdgpu-uninstall  ********  then re-install it using the correct command like you and I mentioned. Now I can use my graphics card in Blender.