# AMDGPU-PRO black screen 16.04

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I'm now to Ubuntu and I would like to install proper AMD drivers for my 290x card.

I installed the AMDGPU-PRO drivers but when I restart the system I see a black screen with a line of text saying something like `blocks 54132/45643` and underneath this there is a flashing white dash, like ready for me to type something, but nothing comes up if I do. I somehow have to remove the drivers now when going into recovery mode on the grub startup page.

I would still like to get proper drivers installed.

I remember when I installed Ubuntu on my laptop once, a while back, that I could select what driver I would like to use on the **Additional Drivers** tab. All I see there now is some kind of proprietary driver for my CPU.

Comment: The text you described "blocks X/Y" sounds more like an issue with your hard disk, than with video drivers. Do the stock open source drivers not work for you?

Comment: it says somthing more like 1451456/5165 xxx (somthing, not sure what)  51354/541352 blocks. I would like to have the best drivers for me available to get the best performance, actually i only want to play some runescape now and then tho. But havent tried to install that yet.

Comment: Well I am using the stock open source amdgpu drivers that are in 16.04 with my R9 Nano, and I can play Borderlands 2 in 4K with all graphics settings turned up to max, no problem. But yeah, the "X/Y blocks" sounds like there was a problem with your hard disk.

Comment: I just reinstalled ubuntu again, how do i see which drivers are used right now and how do i switch? Should i add things for updates or anything before i move on the somthing else like installing a nother driver or app?

Comment: Run `lsmod | grep amdgpu` in a terminal. If it's shown, you should be using the amdgpu driver. If it's not shown, you're likely using the radeon driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)