# Video card driver for ATI RADEON 8670 HD

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics

What driver do I need on Ubuntu for an ATI RADEON 8670 HD. How do I install an ATI driver for the video card as in windows? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 "trusty" with Unity desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the proprietary fglrx driver (known as AMD Catalyst or AMD Radeon Software).
But first, have a look at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)!!

Comment: on setting-software & updates-additional drivers-using x.org xserver -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(open source,tested)..........but have 2 option more i can choose that is your recommended is fglrx.The other  2 fglrx-updates (proprietary) and fglrx (proprietary).Should i choose either one?

Comment: I still recommend you read my suggested link.  You can broke your GUI if you use the wrong driver. Unless you have good knowledge of this, you won't be able to fix it. Some people marked your question as duplicate.

Comment: I need to used the video card drivers because i need to test the virtual machine and run the video converter.I've tried to convert a video under virtual machine but the video and sound is not syncronise but lag the sound.I've search the cause it maybe the drivers.

Comment: what's your OS guest in the VM? Virtual box uses its own video drivers. Maybe, in your case, you should consider have a dual boot machine and use all the machine power to your task.