# Problem with installing AMD driver

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, fglrx, amd-graphics

I tried to install an AMD driver on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04) because Ubuntu is still running on the integrated GPU.

Installation failed.
Here is `fglrx-install.log`:

```
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/15.302/source ->
                 /usr/src/fglrx-15.302

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/15.302/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=4.8.0-45-generic --norootcheck....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-15.302 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-15.302 from DKMS

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 15.302
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

Comment: Fglrx is not supported in 16.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics.

Answer (score 0):

On Intel AMD hybrid graphics you must use prime like this for discrete GPU use

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```