# Install fglrx in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

I am using a laptop with ATI Radeon 8650G. I am unable to install fglrx in Ubuntu 16.04. Can I install the fglrx found in package archives from 14.04?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

FGLRX has been deprecated in 16.04, and I think AMD are moving over to an open driver stack.

If you have a little google around for "fglrx in 16.04" you should find some reports on this quite easily.

So at the moment you are out of luck !