# How to Integrate AMD Radeon R7 M370 with Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, fglrx

Hy folks, I am beginner on Ubuntu.
From couple of days I am trying to integrate AMD graphics card with Ubuntu. I also followed the AMD manual but it didn't work for me. 
I stuck on resolve package dependencies.
Then 
this command didn't performed well:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx-core_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb 
fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb 
fglrx-dev_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb 
fglrx-amdcccle_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
```

Kindly guide me how to get rid of this stuff.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918085/error-processing-package-fglrx-package-fglrx-is-not-configured-yet#comment1448301_918085

Comment: hi @MichaelBay  Now I am working in Ubuntu 14.04.4.  It automatically detects the driver for AMD.

I just install the gazebo5. Neither the gazebo is launching nor it shows some error.

Can you guide me What is the problem then ??

Answer (score 0):

I've strugling with an R7 370and linux  during a couple of days and now it seems that 14.04.5 (.5) does not longer support fglrx i'm not sure is the step i am

It seems basically because 14.04.5 has the kernel and some graphic packages from ubuntu 16 and, in ubuntu 16 fglrx is no longoer supported (it installs, but seems to me that module fglrx is not compiled by a kernel incompatibility)

you can check this article

[Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)

cheers