# Installing Oibaf's Drivers for AMD R5 M430 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

So I have the AMD R5 M430 video card, but there is no official driver so I wanted to seek some open source drivers, and I found this [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics) and after all I read Oibaf's driver (https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) fits good, but I don't know how to install it.

I want a good driver for this video card beacuse I want to use it for gaming and other stuff, I mean I want to use it and ditch the Intel video card beacuse I hate it and I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your instructions you linked, they seem kind of crazy, but really they are very easy to install.  From a terminal window, run the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It should download automatically and install and set up the driver for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I did good in the first time, how can I check if I use the AMD GPU? And stop using the intel

Comment: @sticsk `sudo lshw -c video` should show you the one that is in use.

Comment: @sticsk Or you can run `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`

Comment: @sticsk Also, look here for the hybrid graphics:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know if something's going wrong! I am installing it right now

Comment: so I have this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash XXX.modeset=1" ` Should I write radeon instead of XXX?

Comment: @sticsk Yes it should be `radeon` instead of XXX.

Comment: When I try to connect to my dedicated video card it says Permission Denied, even with `sudo` why?                                                                                `sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`
`bash: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Permission denied`

Comment: @sticsk Unfortunately, I only know how to install the radeon drivers and use them.  My laptop that I did it on was successful, but mine doesn't have Intel on it as a secondary or primary card, or I would know exactly how to do that.

Comment: Well, alright, I gotta ask another question then, thanks for help!

Comment: @sticsk Sorry for a late response back, but I looked at our conversation here and when you were trying to `echo OFF` to the file the `sudo` is not carried over to the `>` part of it.  So the command should be `echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` or `sudo bash -c 'echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch'`