# Which driver should I be using with an HD 7870?

Tags: drivers, games, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS and I've been struggling to get `csgo` to run smoothly. I tried it on the drivers that ship with the OS, as well as the updated Mesa stack and even the AMDGPU drivers.

It could be something else holding back performance, but I'm not sure. I remember being able to play it properly a few years ago on Ubuntu 14.04 with an even weaker GPU (R7 250), but the current configuration is worse.

My specs are:

- Athlon x4 740
- 4 GB RAM
- AMD XFX HD 7870
- 320 GB HDD.

What can I do to fix this and what driver should I use?

Comment: Try installing the oibaf drivers as they are one of the PPAs supporting AMD right now:  https://askubuntu.com/a/939693/231142