# Couldn't get UEFI db list error on system boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 and plan to switch Ubuntu.
I followed a tutorial on how to boot from USB Stick on Windows.

I tried without installing but got this weird error before continuing the boot up.
I also have BIOS mode set to UEFI with enabled Secure Mode.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Security Menu]

[image: Boot Menu]

I dig up before posting, and some suggest that I disabled the Secure Mode, but I don't want to break my current setup on Windows 10, and I'm not 100% sure that will work. Do you have any suggest how to fix this one?

Comment: The install media contains both boot loaders, legacy and UEFI.  Your machine may be able to set a preference of one over the other, so maybe the preference is legacy first, but you only had UEFI on the hard disk.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do? Not really familiar with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Look in your UEFI Settings/BIOS (some key at power-up to invoke, timing may be hard to get right if fast boot is on).  Maybe there is only a Selection of UEFI or legacy (csm mode), but if you are offered a way to set preference, set UEFI before legacy.

Comment: Boot Menu

`
Fast Boot = Enabled,
CMS Support = Disabled (can't change it)
`

Comment: I updated my question with more pictures of BIOS

Comment: BIOS settings look reasonable, but the Secure boot enabled but not active seems odd.  Turning it off to test wont hurt Windows, but that hasn't been necessary for awhile unless you have unsigned proprietary drivers (like Nvidia) Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Did you ever run a media-check on the install media (one of the choices at the grub menu)? Does your install media work on other machines (try mode)?  Try another USB port.

Comment: It happened when doing "Try Mode" but somehow, it doesn't show anymore once I installed it permanently and installed display drivers with update and upgrade command. Btw, thanks.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and after three days accept it to help other people with this problem find a soltuion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to format my windows 10 laptop to ubuntu 18.04.3 using the following steps below:

1. Access grub settings before installation start
2. Add "nomodeset" parameter at the end of "linux" config (*)
3. Save grub setting by pressing "F10" then continue with the installation
4. After restarting, access grub settings to add again the "nodemodeset" (*)
5. Follow these steps for [AMD installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939689/installing-oibafs-drivers-for-amd-r5-m430-on-ubuntu-16-04)
6. Follow these steps for [Hybrid GPU](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)
7. Follow these steps for [disabling wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)
8. Reboot!

(*) - Temporarily add GRUB settings