# How to make drivers seem more recent?

Tags: drivers, steam

I tried to run War thunder off steam but it gave me an error. Digging up I found out you needed at max 6 months old drivers, and I have an HD7890, which means my driver's are 5 years old. Is there any way I can make them seem more recent or make it work? If not I can dual boot to windows and it'll work, but I prefer Ubuntu.
My specs are:
3400G, B450M ds3h and Hd7870 Ghz edition

Comment: I guess you could try the `oibaf` drivers for the AMD HD7890 card.  They are updated almost daily.  https://askubuntu.com/a/939693/231142

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details.  Kernel modules (*drivers*) being so close to the kernel are of course related to both OS & release, and if you're using a LTS release, which stack you opt to use, but you've provided no specifics as to your OS & stack choice.