# Ubuntu with Intel built in + Amd grahic HD radeon 6450 driver installation to connect more than two monitors

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I am using desktop having specification.
i5-3rd/8GB/500GB/Intel Built-in + AMD HD Radeon 6450 graphic card.I have tried so many times to install AMD graphic drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04 to connect monitor on the video card.  I would really appreciate if someone has any kind of documentation or someone did it. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-and-amd-graphics)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried the above link. Still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: It is unclear what is the issue. You don't need to install any drivers. You need to switch BIOS to the discrete card and that's it.