# AMD Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, graphics, 17.04, radeon

I recently started using Ubuntu/Linux and I'm still learning how this works...I'm running in dual boot in a Lenovo G50 80 that has a AMD Radeon R5 M330 (dedicated). So the problem is that I notice that Ubuntu is using my integrated GPU...I am afraid that might decrease performance and I would like to enable the dedicated one. I think I am suposed to download the drivers but in the Additional Drivers section there is nothing there...And assuming I have to use the terminal to download it manually, I don't have any idea how to do it...
So if anyone could help I would be much appreciated.
Thanks

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Can we have that link and then open your terminal and run `sudo lshw -C video | awk -F'product: ' '/product/{print $2}'` and paste into your question

Comment: HD Graphics 5500 (This one is the integrated...)

Comment: Which are you trying to download the drivers?

Comment: The dedicated (AMD Radeon R5 M330)
Because he is already using the HD Graphics 5500

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)