# Screen Resolution Problem in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, screen, display-resolution, vga

I am having a Hp laptop in which I have installed Ubuntu 16.04. When I attached my Dell LCD with Laptop. The screen resolution is 1024 not allowing to increasing the resolution. 
So can u please help me.
I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: We can try helping you if you provide hardware specification, namely graphics. Please [edit] accordingly. Typically it's an issue with (or the absence of) graphics drivers. Also some options limit the available resolutions. Example: Mirroring displays with different native resolutions.

Comment: I am having the RAD-EON GRAPHICS and 1366x768 Max Graphics of my Laptop when i attached by extra screen then it does not allow to go more than 1024x768.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/815592/692175 This answer explains what happened some time ago when Xorg was updated and the old proprietary AMD drivers were no longer compatible. Cannot say the mentioned Oibaf PPA is the solution because I don't use AMD graphics but it looks like many people tried it successfully.

Comment: I am not having AMD Graphics I have an Intel Processor and RADEON Graphics

Comment: "Radeon" means AMD Graphics (former ATI).

Comment: But i cant fix it with that website