# Secondary monitor not being detected anymore after kernel upgrade

Tags: drivers, kernel, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 my secondary screen cannot be detected anymore. I have an AMD Radeon HD 7700M card and my monitor is connected through HDMI or DisplayPort, neither connection works. In Ubuntu 17.04 I had the possibility to revert to an older kernel and then it worked, but now even that older kernel is not working anymore.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/815592/692175

Comment: @MichaelBay, that driver does install but gives me a blank screen.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my laptop which has an AMD APU. Total dealbreaker for me. I need an external monitor to work. Digging around for a solution...

Answer (score -1):

I have a Nvidia 340 driver for my G92 GeForce GTS250 graphics card. I had the monitor not detected the problem after a kernel upgrades from Kernel 4.10.0-42. I just tried out the open source driver and I don't know why but it works and I can get the full-screen showing. Before I had a big black band around the display. I don't know what problems I will have with the open source driver but if nothing serious goes I have to use it or go back to an older kernel. I am using Linux Mint 18.3. This is only a a possible work around if the original driver is proprietory. The open source doesn't take advantage of many of the features of the graphics card I understand. For my purposes I have a functioning monitor.

Comment: I regret to say that I too am confused.  You seem to imply that the open-source driver fixes the problem that occurred with the display.  If this is the case, then you haven't actually posed a question.  And, this forum is only for questions related to Ubuntu.  Questions relating to Linux Mint should be posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://forums.linuxmint.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)