# Second monitor via mini HDMI no longer detected

Tags: display, monitor

When I started my computer this morning, all of a sudden the system wasn't detecting my second monitor, which was working just fine until last night... I'm running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

Under **System Settings** > **Displays**, nothing happens when I click on *Detect Displays*.

Can anyone give me some advice on where begin troubleshooting this please?

---

**UPDATE**

In response to someone's questions asking for details, this is the output of running the `xrandr -q` command.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: does  `xrandr -q` show the 2nd display as connected to system

Comment: hello. I have updated my question with the output of that command... It seems like it doesn't display it as connected.

Comment: perhaps a hardware or cable connection issue. Also upgrading ubuntu kernels could cause the problem (https://askubuntu.com/questions/971788/secondary-monitor-not-being-detected-anymore-after-kernel-upgrade)