# Installing AMDGPU-PRO on ubuntu 16.04.03 with a radeon rx vega 56

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I just got a radeon rx vega 56 and I have been trying to get it to work with ubuntu. I use dual monitors and when booting up ubuntu for the first time I only can use one screen and it has bad resolution, and the other screen is blank. I started installing AMDGPU-PRO with the AMD guide here:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

I have done everything that the guide says and then I restarted my computer. When the computer restarts I see the ubuntu splash screen on both monitors. After awhile it will say that the computer is running in low graphics mode. I have tried all options but I can not get it to load. Is there something else that I should be doing or an easier way to install this? Or should the default driver include resolution and dual monitor support and something else could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-17-10-and-amd-graphics/815592#815592

Comment: AMDGPU-PRO does support a rx vega 56, the problem is I can not get AMDGPU-PRO to work.

Comment: Did you try Oibaf's driver?

Comment: When I run lshw -c video it says the display is unclaimed and shows nothing for the configuation

Answer (score 1):

Have u checked linux-headers version ? I tried to install that driver on my mining rig several times, it hadn't work util I found out that the driver only support linux-headers-4.10.xx , and the Ubuntu 16.04.03 upgraded the kernel to header-4.13.xx (after I accidentally typed: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade) . So try the following:

1. Find out the linux header version of your Ubuntu:

   dpkg -l | grep linux

   if your lastest linux-headers/image > 4.10.xx (e.g: 4.13.xxx)) then
2. Uninstall it:

   sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-xxx (your newer version)

   sudo apt-get purge linux-image-xxx
3. Reboot: sudo reboot
4. Uninstall the amdgpu-pro driver
5. Reboot
6. Reinstall then amdgpu driver

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, try the HWE kernel. I have a Vega 64 and fixed an issue I had when I started using that.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack