# Install AMD Topaz XT Radeon R7 driver on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I want to install AMD graphics card driver on Ubuntu 17.10 running laptop. I don't know whether the radeon driver has already installed and running. Is the graphics card in use? If not how can I install it's driver?

Output for `sudo lshw -C video -C cpu`

```
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: U3E1
       size: 500MHz
       capacity: 2800MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
       configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 520
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:c1000000-c1ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2300000-c233ffff memory:c2340000-c235ffff
```

`lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA` give this output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: It says, `driver=amdgpu`, installed and in use. You don't need to install anything.

Comment: Then if I run gimp or any other graphics dependent software, will the graphics card be used? 


When  I launch firefox, the window shown black for a little time, seeing this I have fallen in confusion that whether the graphics card is in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10/17.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-16-10-17-10-and-amd-graphics)

Comment: As mentioned it states the amdgpu driver is enabled. However, you are on a hybrid system. What does the _Details_ for system info under Settings say? I expect it probably lists the Intel graphics as being used.

Comment: @mikewhatever: I believe your first comment holds the answer. Would you mind to convert it to an answer?

Comment: @Jenin You might also want to try logging out, and selecting the Xorg session instead of the default Wayland session, at the password entry screen, by clicking on the gear icon there, to see if it helps resolve some of the issues you're having with Firefox or other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It says, `driver=amdgpu`, installed and in use. You don't need to install anything.

<sup>(source: [comment by mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984466/install-amd-topaz-xt-radeon-r7-driver-on-ubuntu-17-10#comment1583887_984466))</sup>

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!