# Team fortress 2 very slow with Ubuntu 17.17 and Caicos graphic card

Tags: graphics, 17.10, amd-graphics

I could play TF2 normally with windows with my current hardware. I ditched Windows 10 because my license was revoked after I changed my motherboard.

Now trying TF2 with Ubuntu 17.10, it appears very slow, nearly unplayable. I'm not into playing. I would just like to know if the configuration is OK.

I could run Web3D examples [here](https://threejs.org/) without problem. I don't know how to determine if the 3D is software or hardware generated. I get only 17FPS for [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer). I had 60fPS on Windows with all examples with the exact same hardware. I have the impression the 3D acceleration is not functioning.

**EDIT1**: Graphic card is Sapphire Radeon AMD R5 230 2G DDR3, CPU is i5-7400

**EDIT2**: I have 2 screens.

Comment: What's a "Caicos graphic card"? What matters is the chipset (Nvidia, AMD, other?) and some require proprietary drivers for performance, just like in Windows. And, about Windows (off topic remark), licenses aren't revoked with a motherboard change, it just requires reactivation.

Comment: @MichaelBay, thanks for looking at my question. I added the graphic card info. Sorry, forgot it. I got a free upgrade to Windows 10 form a previous version (not OEM), but when I changed the mother board, my license was told to be invalid. It was confirmed to me on the Microsoft support forum that a change of motherboard would invalidate my W10 license.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)