# AMD drivers for Ubuntu 17.10(AMD Radeon R5 M330)

Tags: 17.10, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I need drivers for AMD Radeon R5 M330. I currently use Ubuntu 17.10 on a dell laptop.

I saw a few links -
[Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics) etc but the major answer I got was to downgrade. 
Now is there another method available?

{AMDPro dosen't support my graphics card.}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `oibaf` driver? In the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), it says that the suggested version of Ubuntu is `17.10` version, you can try it out.