# Screen tearing only while on battery

Tags: drivers, radeon, battery, amd-graphics, tearing

I have finally decided to start using Linux on my np355v5c laptop which has AMD HD 7660G & HD 7670M, everything works (almost) perfectly, except that when I unplug the cable, the screen starts to tear especially on the cursor, if I plug it back everything goes back to normal.

I have Kubuntu 16.04 installed and I didn't install any drivers so I think I am using the pre-installed opensource ones.

Note: the problem does NOT happen in bios or when I had windows 10 installed, it happens on freshly installed Ubuntu.

Hope I can get some help here because I really liked Linux and don't want to go back to windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/815592/796132) which solved the problem by downgrading to 14.04 lts..

Hope to see the open-source drivers getting better before April 2019 :D