# how to install the amd graphic card driver?

Tags: amd-graphics

i just install ubuntu 18.04 and i cant install the amd proprietary driver because it's not compatible with linux kernel 4 or above.
Now i want to install the open source driver, is it already installed or should i install it and how ?
My graphic card is:
Amd radeon hd 7640g + 7670m dual switchable graphics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-Source drivers are already installed.

If you want to get the proprietary drivers working or would just like to possibly improve the performance of your card, check out [this excellent tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

Comment: I've just installed KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04 based) and I can't see the 4K resolution option in the screen configuration. Should I follow this tutorial inasmuch as I have a AMD Raden HD 6850?