# Problem with rx 480

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, nomodeset

I can't boot my Ubuntu 18.04 machine without using  `nomodeset` in grub, to start the live usb for the installation.
I needed that command too and without it the system stucks with a weird screen.

I tried to update the drivers, a fresh install and even use the AMDGPU drivers from amd (in this case the system doesnt start at all).

Can you help me?

Here the output of lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3:

2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] [1002:67df] (rev c7)
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580] [174b:e353]
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
2d:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580] [1002:aaf0]

Right now i dont have the Amdgpu drivers installed because i was forced to reinstall again.

Comment: Hello innerd, and welcome to askubuntu! Please add the following to your post: **1.** output of `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3` **2.** add more info of the installedh amd driver; how did you installed it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: Ok edited the original post with the informations needed, i installed the drivers with "./amdgpu-pro-install -y" command in terminal

Comment: i tried Oibaf's driver too without results

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm having the same issue.