# AMD Graphics card (R5 M430) driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 18.04, amd-graphics

I have Lenovo Ideapad 110 laptop with *AMD A8-7410 APU and a dedicated graphics card R5 M430*. I have loaded Ubuntu 18.04 on it. But, there is no driver available for the dedicated graphics card. I tried Oibaf graphics drivers with no luck.

How to get the drivers for R5 M430, and make the graphics card working? Need help. Thanks.

**lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"**

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] [1002:9851] (rev 45)

01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

**lsmod | grep drm**

```
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 amdgpu,radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  20 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

**fgrep drm ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.*.log**

```
[  1515.492] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1515.496] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
```

Comment: How do you mean no driver is available for the card? Please add the error message you get to your post.

Comment: I mean, there is no proprietary drivers available for that particular graphics card. My problem is that I'm not able to use the dedicated graphics card without appropriate drivers. Oibaf also not detecting the card.

Comment: How do you mean you are not able to use the card without proprietary drivers? What problems do you experience? What errors do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors as such. The video is rendered by integrated graphics which occupies memory (~1.3GB) from RAM. If I'm able to switch to dedicated graphics, I would save the RAM. In AMD's site driver for the particular graphics card is available only for windows. Please suggest drivers/methods to make use of my graphics card.

Comment: And the `radeon` (or `amdgpu` if it's a newer model) doesn't support the card? Please add the output of `lsmod | grep drm` and `fgrep drm ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.*.log` to your question.

Comment: Added the required information to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the `radeon` driver _is_ the driver for your discrete card (or the `amdgpu` if the card is a newer model). Unless you have a specific need to install the proprietary drivers, you're all set.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL` terminal command.