# Macbook Pro Graphics Driver - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 19.04, macbook, apple

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 19.04 on my 2015 Macbook Pro (linux is primary OS).

**How would I go about getting the updated (or proprietary) graphics drivers for this machine?**

The AMD site gives some .deb files for various graphics cards, but I do not see one that matches the specs on apple's website.

*https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r9-series/amd-radeon-r9-300-series/amd-radeon-r9-m375*

### *https://support.apple.com/kb/sp719?locale=en_US*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well DRAM Controller [8086:0d04] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Crystal Well DRAM Controller [106b:0148]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0d01] (rev 08)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x8 Controller [8086:0d05] (rev 08)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x4 Controller [8086:0d09] (rev 08)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:8c16] (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c4b] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [8086:8c24] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] [1002:6821] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Radeon R9 M370X Mac Edition [106b:0149]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1002:aab0]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [106b:0149]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0152]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
05:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
    Kernel driver in use: bdc-pci
    Kernel modules: bdc_pci
06:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
07:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
07:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
07:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
07:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
07:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
08:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013] [8086:156c]
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt
```

Comment: Have you fully installed Ubuntu yet? If not, run BootCamp on the device. It should have support for Linux, last I checked.

Comment: What makes you think there is an updated or proprietary driver for that card? Also, instead of posting a bunch apple links, add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA` to the question.

Comment: grep VGA is no good, There may be `3D` adapter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install AMD graphic drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: You don't need any drivers.