# I may installed wrong apt-repository and packages while reinstalling GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, apt, kubuntu, amd-graphics, add-apt-repository

A general question: If I think I've added wrong apt-repository and installed wrong GPU drivers, what I should do?

---

About my situation:
I have Kubuntu 19.04 and AMD R9 280X (HD 7970/8970).
Because I had some graphic issues I tried to (re)install drivers.

I found another [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1066106/1004813) and I followed step-by-steps. One package was missing while following steps, so I started to install it but then I noticed the missing package (what I already started to install) was GDM3 (GNOME Display Manager). I saw my mistake, and removed it.

I know, "check first what you are installing". I'm still new with these stuff...

Now I afraid I've done something wrong so my system will not properly boot or I get other errors after restarting my PC. So I wanted to ask some tips from you guys before doing more damage (if I even made any).

My GPU related apk-repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

```
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list.save
oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-disco.list
oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-disco.list.save
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-mesa-bionic.list
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-mesa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-mesa-bionic.list.save
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-pkppa-bionic.list
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-pkppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-pkppa-bionic.list.save
paulo-miguel-dias-ubuntu-pkppa-disco.list
```

The correct apt-repository what I think I need is `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa` (stable).

`sudo lshw -c video` shows `driver=radeon` which (I think) is correct

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I tried to grep installed packages, but I don't know (and didn't find) a suitable command for this.

Comment: I'm not sure, if my old command is working this days. `dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'| egrep -v "archive.ubuntu.com|/var/lib/dpkg/status" | awk '{printf "%-30s %-36s %-60s %-20s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}'` I have only 1 ppa. For that command the ppa's have to be active.

Comment: @nobody If not sure the command works, why post it?!

Comment: It works in my case, but I have only uuku as ppa, so I made only a comment. Don't strike me down :D.

Comment: @markspk Not sure what you've tried to achieve by following the answer. It deals with installing amdgpu from a ppa, which in your case seems irrelevant. Also, the part of the answer with reconfiguring and reinstalling is just stupid. The best tip I can think of is get rid of PPAs.

Comment: @mikewhatever Okay, thanks for answering! So I just remove all the related PPAs, make a apt-get update & upgrade, and then readd a stable PPA?

Comment: Well, I don't know what "a stable PPA" is, but if that's what you want, good luck.