# Installing AMD Graphic Driver, Enabling hardware acceleration for HD 4250, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I tried to use fglrx, which isn't up to date anymore (I can't install it, but I allowed the repository thing in Ubuntu Software Center). After that I tried [How to install AMD graphic drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) from Joshua and that didn't worked too.

AMDGPUPro isn't a solution, because it doesn't support the GPU I have.

Now I don't know what I am able to do, since the other answers are outdated.

Comment: The proper driver here is `radeon`, and it should be installed and loaded. So, you need not do anything.

Comment: @mikewhatever That could be maybe true that it's already loaded, but there is no "hardware acceleration" turned on, and there are no informations about the driver how I am able to activate it.

Comment: Old cards may not have hardware acceleration available for many video codecs, and as Radeon HD 4250 is 10 years old, it is not unexpected.  There is no mention of what you want to accelerate, which makes the question somewhat vague.