# kernel 5.4.0-58 causes old amd radeon to stop working

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine.. it has old gpu, Amd Radeon 8570M. it works fine with the default kernel, 5.4.0-26. But after I installed some App that uses DKMS, the kernel got updated to 5.4.0-58 and my gpu is not working anymore..

after that I planned to install the amdgpu driver from AMD official website but my GPU is not supported anymore. how can I fix this? I've tried installing old driver from AMD but it refuses to install.. I'm in confusion right now :(

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` shows :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: What "app" did you install? Most likely the problem is with it. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. What do you mean by "my gpu is not working anymore"?

Comment: I installed Autodesk EAGLE and VirtualBox. but this problem actually happens to me from 1 month ago when I'm installing amdgpu driver to overclock my gpu

Comment: Your adapter isn't detected by PCI. It is not a software issue. Try to take it out, clean and sit back properly. Or maybe you've burnt it by overclocking ;-)

Comment: You can always boot with a previos kernel and check if it works there.

Comment: It's a broken laptop converted to PC. with only board and VGA display.. I can't remove the GPU

Comment: I posted this with my 5.4.0-26 kernel :) it seems like 5.4.0-58 broke my amd related files/softwares :( now even with 5.4.0-26 amd wont work :'(

Comment: You don't have any AMD GPUs there ;-)

Comment: my device have amd gpu :-) it's working at the morning.. its a Lenovo 20235

Comment: But `lspci` doesn't prove it ;-) What does plain `lspci` show?

Comment: Hmm, I'm more confused now :( wait i recheck my other settings

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my AMD Radeon HD 8570M is working again (Yay! :D).

I followed instruction from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) but I installed `linux-firmware` too.
I dont know if linux-firmware is related to my issue or not. I just followed the instruction and applying my fix (installing linux firmware and 3x reboots). and now my 8570M works :D