# AMD Radeon Graphic Card Seen as 'Unknown Display' after Installing Ubuntu Bionic 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I am trying to install Bionic 18.04 on a Gigabyte Z390 motherboard. After 3 attempts I still get the same result over and over again when looking at Devices --> Displays --> Unknown Display.

We are speaking here of an [AMD] ASRock Radeon RX 5700 XT Taichi X 8G OC+ which is well recognized by Windows 7 on the same computer.

Hence the resolution gets stuck at 1024 x 768 ! what a feature on a 4K HD capable board.

Is there something broken within the hardware detection on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 ?

Running the lspci command

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

Returns

`03:00.0 VGA Compatible Controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:731f] (rev c1)`

Which is quite laconic as a precise identification ... Maybe not a surprise there isn't any kind of driver installed.

Though this reference identify correctly the card as

`1002:731F --- Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5700 / 5700 XT]`

is reported on this [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/1501498/how-to-accurately-identify-an-amd-gpu).

I am using 18.04.3 amd64 ISO image since the 18.04.4 image couldn't get the appropriate bcmwl-kernel-source package working with the installed kernel ...

I have seen some answers here like '[How to install AMD graphic drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)' but I quickly run in not install-able packages due to missing / broken dependencies.

Why do we have to deal with such a mess when using Apple compatible hardware ?

In the `About` screen I see

```
Graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
GNOME 3.28.2
```

llvmpipe isn't at all from AMD I believe. Why do I get this as Graphics ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why but on the 4th attempt and after installing the updates (like on the previous attempts), Ubuntu manages after the reboot to show a 4K HD display ... Without having to try to install or re-install anything.

The `About` screen saying:

`Graphics AMD® Radeon RX 5700 XT`

A further note : Installing the 18.04.3 ISO Image without access to the Internet installed Kernel 5.0 and the working MacIntosh Wi-Fi support from package `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Later the update installed Kernel 5.4 and the Wi-Fi Internet was still working on both Kernels.

When I tried installing 18.04.4 ISO Image it installed Kernel 5.4 and the Wi-Fi was not working. Trying to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` failed as well.