# Ubuntu 18.04 Display brightness not working - Unknown Display in settings

Tags: drivers, graphics, brightness, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I have a new ThinkPad E15 Gen 3 [link to Lenovo's website](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpade/thinkpad-e15-gen-3-(15%E2%80%9D-amd)/20yg008cus) that I purchased less than a month ago. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it and the installation went smoothly. However, when I tried to change the brightness, it doesn't work. I turn on the PC from suspend, and the display doesn't work. After reading online it seems that it might be a display driver issue. However, there is no discrete GPU just an integrated one.

Things that I tried:

1. Changing display manager to `lightdm` from `gdm`
2. Adding `nomodeset=0` to `grub` and running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting.
3. Checking Additional Drivers in the Software app.
4. Adding `oibaf` using `ppa:repository` and checking if display drivers are installed that way.
5. Checked if I could install the drivers using `ubuntu-drivers` and the `autoinstall` option that comes with that package.
6. Also followed the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) which nearly crashed my PC.
7. Re-installing Ubuntu 18.04.

I would really appreciate some help with this problem. My laptop is crucial to my research work and unfortunately over the course of 3 days I've been able to perform little to none of it because of this issue. The stress is really getting to me and I've become super unproductive without my machine. I purchased a ThinkPad because I thought Linux would run right out of the box.

I'd appreciate any help and would be more than willing to run any commands/dump logs etc, if that would help with debugging.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this will help - but have you tried using the keyboard shortcuts for your hardware? I think Thinkpads use fn-home / fn-end to adjust brightness (but there may be symbols on the keys that tell you what to press, or you can probably find out from the device’s documentation). I believe those actions are independent of the os so might help?

Comment: @Will thank you for your suggestion. When I press the Fn+Brightness (up/down) I can see the logo of the sun on the screen with the brightness bar going left and right but the screen brightness remains the same. Furthermore, when I check display in settings it says "Unknown Display" and I cannot change any display setting including orientation, night light etc. Hope this helps. (Also, I ran `xrandr` and it says failed to capture gamma value, not sure if that helps)