# AMD Radeon 530 in Ubuntu

Tags: gpu-driver

now that there are past a few months. I do have the same Problem.
I have an
Dell Inspiron 17 5770 2018, Core i7-8550U, 16GB RAM, 2TB HDD, 256GB SSD (5770-0371)

and it has a graphicscard AMD Radeon 530, 4GB, HDMI.

I tried installing the driver on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 . None of them is working.
Is there a solution?

Comment: how are you trying to install the drivers? PPA or downloaded from AMD website? please post the output of `sudo lshw -class video`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

I find Mesa drivers great with my R9 390, RX 480 and RX 580

Comment: Could you help me install it?

Comment: I tried installing it. But it doesn't work