# I can't change my graphic card's driver 18.04

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I've R5 220 Graphic card. When I open the software-properties-gtk I can see 2 drivers which are `xserver-xorg-video-ati` `fglrx` and I want to use xserver-xorg-video-ati driver instead of fglrx. Here is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

It does not change it, How can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why net? It gives ethernet controllers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: This is the correct driver `radeon` for this card. There is nothing that needs or may be changed. This is the only driver for this card that can be used on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: Okay, I suppose I do not need to change.