# AMD drivers for Ubuntu 20.04-64 bit

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I've tried to install AMD proprietary drivers on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer and came across several installation problems which, fortunately, did not impair the quality of the display (probably because I removed any AMD driver remnants before rebooting). Although the installation guide is quite informative and detailed, I could not circumvent the many dependency issues that arose. One thing called my attention: the latest driver for my graphics card dates back to 2014 (14.04), what's somewhat strange. That is, provided I'm identifying my card right... Here there are some outputs:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:126 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dfe20000-dfe3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**hardinfo** says the following about the graphics:

```
OpenGL
Vendor  X.Org
Renderer    AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-72-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
Version 3.1 Mesa 20.2.6
Direct Rendering    Yes
```

This leaves me a bit undecided about what driver(s) should I download... The first output suggests that drivers for either the Radeon HD 6450, 7450, 8450 or R5 230 would work fine (I tried the one for the 6450). The installation manual also mentions a graphical selection tool called **amd-driver-installer-catalyst-14-12-x86.x86_64.run** which might have made my life easier, but which I was not able to find.

Therefore, I'm somewhat lost as for what I should do. I believe the display might have some room for graphics improvement (sharpness, etc) but ain't sure if it's worth paying the risk of a misinstallation and/or a serious graphics issue.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What architecture is your computer?

Comment: @Jeff, it's a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100F CPU @ 3.60GHz, 8112MB RAM, running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Kernel 5.4.0-72-generic (x86_64). Anything else?

Comment: I don't think you can install AMD drivers on Intel architecture... I will look into it.

Comment: I was looking at this thread... There may be something on here that can help you: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/amd-drivers-on-intel-cpu.2307137/

Comment: You have *radeon*, the one and only driver for your AMD card, already installed. The package you found is obsolete. AMD drivers are now distributed with Ubuntu and the best drivers automatically selected. @Jeff AMD graphics drivers are for graphics card/chipsets. You can have an AMD card with an Intel CPU.

Comment: @Jeff This thread here was enlightening, albeit somewhat old. It tells a lot about AMD drivers.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics

Comment: I find that old resources an be very helpful for solving new problems.