# Which NVIDIA driver do I need?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have migrated my system to a new computer using a Gigabyte AORUS X570 I WIFI MB running Ubuntu 20.04-04. I tried to run the Zoom app and the system hung after a few minutes (completely frozen and had to power off/on). Reading some of the suggested possible remedies, one was to install the video driver from NVIDIA and use it instead of the Ubuntu default driver. However, on trying to ascertain which driver to download from the AMD site, I cannot correlate the information there with the information I have on my MB on the Gigabyte website. I am using a AMD RYZEN 5 5600G with integrated graphics. I feel kind of dumb asking this question but which NVIDIA driver do I install from the AMD site?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't know who told you to use an NVIDIA driver with AMD integrated graphics, but they are wrong. That _may_ fix the problem _if you has an NVIDIA graphics card_ (like an NVIDIA GTX 1050). But you don't, you have integrated AMD graphics.

Comment: Best practice with a major hardware change is to reinstall the OS. Sometimes you can get away with not having to do it. Based on your problems, you should reinstall the OS.  After installation, you should not need to download, install, or configure any additional drivers for your GPU.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why re you looking for an Nvidia Driver in the AMD site?

It's just another Brand!, you should look for an nvidia driver in the nvidia site. https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

And AMD driver in the AMD site. https://www.amd.com/en/support

How did you migrate your system? ,. it would be easier to format!

Comment: Ha, yes, in the end that is what I had to do - start from scratch and rebuild the system and then restore user data and install my apps.  The reason I went to the AMD site was because the integrated graphic is on the AMD cpu and I know they own NVIDIA so I thought that is where I would find the correct driver.  I guess I am wrong. Thanks for your response. I guess my understanding of how integrated graphics are defined is wrong.

Comment: @user3147955 Um... I don't think that's quite right. In terms of GPUs, NVIDIA and AMD are direct competitors. AMD does not own NVIDIA. Perhaps you're thinking of NVIDIA buying ARM (not AMD, ARM), but [I believe that deal was cancled](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/7/22922731/nvidia-no-longer-buying-acquiring-arm-reportedly). If you have any more questions, feel free [to ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: @cocomac Thanks for that clarification and the offer. Not hitting on all cylinders today.