# VS Code is very laggy on Ubuntu 20.04 when running my integrated AMD Renoir Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver, integrated

I'm new to Ubuntu, and Linux in general. My machine is running on UEFI with On-Demand Graphics, and am running Ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot. I have an integrated AMD Renoir GPU and a dedicated NVIDIA GPU, and have installed the recommended nvidia drivers.

I observed a similar issue with Chromium-based browsers, and had to turn off the hardware acceleration for it to work smoothly.

I also tried running VS Code after switching to my dedicated GPU, and can confirm it works smoothly. However, I want to avoid doing so for battery related reasons.

My questions are as follows:

- I understand that I can do something similar with VS Code by using the `--disable-gpu` parameter, but I'd like to know why I can't have it run properly on the integrated graphics card.
- Do I need to install AMD-specific drivers along with the nvidia ones? Is that even possible? How do people handle GPU usage on systems with integrated and dedicated cards?

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: I don't think it does. I'm currently using the recommended nvidia drivers from ubuntu-drivers. While everything works fine when I'm on my NVIDIA card, the stuttering happens when I'm using the integrated AMD Card. No amd drivers were listed when I observed the output from `ubuntu-drivers`, and I don't know enough to figure out if installing amd drivers will remove the nvidia ones.

Comment: You didn't read what I wanted you to read. Don't install AMD graphics drivers that you don't need. The AMD graphics drivers are built-in in Ubuntu, and don't interfere with the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers at all.