# Ubuntu loads a black screen

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

This is the first time that I've installed Ubuntu, and it's a dual boot. Ubuntu is installed on a 500GB SSD. It loads to a black screen and doesn't allow any hotkeys to invoke a terminal. If I boot into failsafe mode it loads a default GUI fine (it doesn't adapt to my screen size, but at least it loads), but obviously that's not ideal.

My graphics card is a AMD Radeon RX 550. AFAIK I downloaded the proprietary drivers just fine, but nothing seems to work. I have no idea what to do now, and I will be forced to uninstall the whole thing if it doesn't work.

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-install
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version               Architecture Description
+++-==============-=====================-============-=========================>
ii  amdgpu-install 22.10.2.50102-1416363 all          AMDGPU driver repository
```

Comment: No proprietary drivers required. Simply install Ubuntu and you should be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: I didn't do anything out of the ordinary. It never worked in the first place, installign ubunbtu without doing anything. I need a step-by-step guide, I don't know much about Ubuntu or linux for that matter.

Comment: Thanks Karel, but I don't know what to do with that info, I just need step by step how to know what's wrong.