# Trouble installing AMD drivers on Ubuntu Studio

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics, ubuntu-studio, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I am trying out Ubuntu Studio 22.04.01 and was trying to install the latest AMD GPU drivers. My card is a 5700XT, and I downloaded the drivers [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt).

After following their instructions to install the package, and then following the instructions to use `amdgpu-install --vulkan=amdvlk,pro`, I keep receiving this error message here:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease            
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease        
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease      
Hit:5 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/22.20/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:6 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.2 ubuntu InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-lowlatency is not available, but is
referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-lowlatency' has no installation candidate
```

Even when I tried using the regular `amdgpu-install` it still fails and gives the exact same error!

I believe I have some AMD drivers installed because when I ran `glxinfo -B`, there are AMD drivers that did pop up. But they're slightly outdated which wouldn't be a problem really. But I cannot use blender's current HIP features without having the latest drivers, as Blender told me so.

Should I be doing some kind of update command instead? Or does my distro not support this latest AMD driver yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: The error "inux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-lowlatency is not available" seems unrelated to "AMD drivers". Lowlatency kernels have nothing to do with AMD. Whatever "drivers" you've installed worked, unless there were other errors.

Comment: In a nutshell, for many years now, AMD Graphics run with open-source drivers already selected during the Ubuntu installation. No user action required.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! The problem comes in with Blender honestly, because it keeps not detecting my GPU through the HIP Cycle Render. I'll post an image link down below for reference:
https://i.imgur.com/9pT6qCW.png

I believe it is suppose to be supported, it shows up here:
https://community.amd.com/t5/radeon-pro-graphics/blender-3-0-and-amd-creating-a-new-performance-path/ba-p/499333

In the mean time I think I was able to update using Mesa drivers using this repository:
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
It updated from 20 something to 22.3.0. But Blender still gives the same error.

Comment: Apologies as I should have probably mention the whole "Blender HIP" thing from the start as this was what I was trying to accomplish and that is why I was trying to update my drivers.  Not sure what to do after this or how to get Blender to utilize my GPU. Should I use specific drivers, a specific Blender version, or a different distro?

Answer (score 1):

Take everything I say down below as an inexperienced user, and to be honest I do not know exactly what each command does, only from what they say from the documentation.
I ended up just messing around with a lot of trial and error to get it to work. So this may or may not work for someone else.  I might try this again at some point and do a more thorough documentation.

I ended up also rebooting my PC quite a few times to make sure after each large update it would pick up the new stuff. So I'll document these down too.

**------Step 1------**

By following this link, scroll down to "Jonathan - joni999" replied message that will provide the answers you need to this problem.
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/blender-amd-and-opencl/40199/8
Basically you want to get "hipcc" which I think is the official HIP libraries for AMD GPUs, by running these commands:

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt install clang
sudo apt install comgr
sudo apt-get -y install rocm-dkms
```

**Reboot the computer**

I found this by finding the official documentation from AMD here:
https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/HIP-Installation.html

**------Step 2------**

In the step 2 of "joni999" message, I came across the same problem as them where it didn't create "/opt/rocm/bin", so I follow the link they provided to install "ROCm".
BUT I followed a slightly different route by using the "upstream kernel drivers" instead, so that it uses the latest drivers. I'll write down my process here. You follow the normal procedure of installing:

**(fair warning, the commands below will obviously restart your PC after the update)**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libnuma-dev
sudo reboot
```

Then run this:

```
wget -qO - http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/ xenial main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
```

If you run into warnings, you can ignore them. However if you run into actual errors updating gpg key stuff, or something related to keys being expired, then I believe you can run this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys f7f8147431c75e505c58a6f3a3548510869357a6 rocm.gpg.key
```

(not sure if this above command will work because I didn't run into any actual errors, just simple warnings, but will leave it here just in case)

**------Step 3------**

Then you proceed to install the actual ROCm development packages instead of the regular "ROCK" version as they call it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rocm-dev
```

**Reboot the computer**

Now you to need to make sure the actual user account you are using has "group permissions" to use the GPU. Type in:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

I believe you change "$LOGNAME" with the username of your account.
So for me it was "sudo usermod -a -G video dareth"

Now, below you can run this optional commands but I'd recommend adding them just in case, as apparently they'll ensure all future created accounts or users on the PC would have access to the GPU as well:

```
echo 'ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/adduser.conf
echo 'EXTRA_GROUPS=video' | sudo tee -a /etc/adduser.conf
```

Now the next command will make it easier for apps to utilize the ROCm.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rocm/bin:/opt/rocm/profiler/bin:/opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/rocm.sh
```

**Reboot the computer**

**------Step 4------**

Everything should work fine now BUT if Blender still does not pick up your AMD GPU under HIP, then try also installing the actual "ROCK" packages on top of the development ones.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rocm-dkms
```

**Reboot the computer**

You GPU should now show up under HIP in Blender after.

Comment: My apologies, I went and edited my answer above and tried to include the steps I THINK I followed but to be honest, I can't exactly quite remember what I did. So there may be something I missed.  But I feel pretty sure if you did everything above there then it should work (hopefully)!
At some point I might try doing this all over again and then I'll properly document my steps and then upload it as a guide somewhere.
I am definitely not expert on this matter, so take everything I say with a grain of salt haha.